# Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in yii2

Tags: yii2

> I've got error Object of class Closure could not be converted to string on this code

```
 [
        'format'=>'raw',
       'attribute' =>'patron_firstName',
         'value' => function($model,$key,$index)
         {

             $firstName=$name->patron_firstName;
             $lastName=$name->patron_lastName;
             $fullName=$firstName." ".$lastName;
             return $fullName;
        }


        ],
```

I have use this in detail view of yii2 .
How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use anonymous function in detail view  you can use the assign or and normal function  eg:

```
 [
    'format' => 'raw',
    'attribute' => 'patron_firstName',
    'value' => $model->firstName . " " . $model->lastName;
 ],
```

or

```
function fullname($model) {
    return  $model->firstName . " " . $model->lastName;
}

[
    'format' => 'raw',
    'attribute' => 'patron_firstName',
    'value' => fullname()
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You surely cannot use closures like this, but also you're missing `using ($name)` in the definition in order to access that variable.

Why you don't just use:

```
[
    'format'=>'raw',
    'attribute' =>'patron_firstName',
    'value' => "{$name->patron_firstName} {$name->patron_lastName}"
],
```

Much cleaner and readable in my opinion.